# How do I split this captcha image into 5 pieces for each words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

Here is the image

[image: https://i.ibb.co/pjQcD10/b.gif]

It is a captcha image and it has 5 characters. I want to crop the image into 5 different pieces and every cropped image will be same sized and contain a character.

Here is what I tried but it is cropping from random sides and doesn't contain any character at all.

```
import image_slicer

image_slicer.slice('b.png', 5)
```

Comment: `every cropped image will be same sized and contain a character.` - Unless the font is mono-spaced (and it's not), it won't work.

Comment: @h4z3 is it possible to get only pieces that contains characters at least?

Comment: On possible way through this could be, character recognition using `cv2` and creating a box around recognized characters. Then use the boundaries of the box for cropping the image